# SQL Server 2005 Get Login name from User name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can i specify a user name for a specific database and get the Login for that user in a query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the [Security Catalog Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178542.aspx), you can get database and server principal information, like so:

```
USE [database_name]

SELECT sp.name AS login_name
FROM sys.server_principals sp
JOIN sys.database_principals dp ON (sp.sid = dp.sid)
WHERE dp.name = 'user_name'
```

I can't find a view that will give you all users, regardless of database, so this needs to be run within the context of the database of the login.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * 
FROM
sys.server_principals AS log
WHERE
(log.type in ('U', 'G', 'S', 'C', 'K') AND log.principal_id not between 101 and 255 AND log.name <> N'##MS_AgentSigningCertificate##')
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use the system stored procedure [sp_helpuser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187732.aspx).

```
exec sp_helpuser 'Username'
```

Comment: How can i select only the login from the results of this sp?