# Get login name in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an orphan user in sql server and I want to get the login name not the user name because they are not the same, I didn't find a solution that correspond to my needs.

[image: login name]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 Get Login name from User name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643443/sql-server-2005-get-login-name-from-user-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
execute as login = 'LCF\jmp'
select distinct name
from sys.login_token
where principal_id > 0
      and type = 'WINDOWS GROUP';
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to get it using :

```
SELECT suser_name()
```

Docs Link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-name-transact-sql

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns a login name only if the login has an entry in syslogins which is not my case.

Comment: The docs indicate that, although on a test server, where I have no login in syslogins, it still brings back the correct login for me.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/original-login-transact-sql) is what you need:

```
SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your user is `Windows` user, so it can login to server due to its membership in some `Windows groups`.

To find out these groups run the query:

```
execute as login = 'LCF\jmp'
select distinct name
from sys.login_token
where principal_id > 0
      and type = 'WINDOWS GROUP';
```

And mind that it's not "orphaned", it need not to have it's `sid` mapped to server to be able to connect to server, Windows groups `sid`s are enough.

Answer (score 1):

> On MSSQL 2014 use

```
select SYSTEM_USER
```